# How to programm a timer on vba that runs over midnight?

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I am coding a process on VBA, for which I am using a basic timer.

```
dim t as single

T=timer 
(code...)
Range("A1") = Timer - t & " secs"
```

My timer should be able to keep running after midnight. However I have read that the timer rest at 24:00. Is it possible to set a timer that is not influence by the passage over midnight?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need the date as well as the time

Set the function to run across midnight, with these variables:

```
Dim StartDate As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
```

Dim CurrentDate As Long
Dim CurrentTime As Double

Dim dblStartDateTime   As Double
Dim dblCurrentDateTime As Double
Dim dblElapsedDateTime As Double

StartDate = Date
StartTime = VBA.Timer

dblStartDateTime = StartDate + (StartTime / 24 / 3600)

You'll notice that dblStartDateTime looks a lot like the normal DateTime that you get back from VBA.Now() - but it's got the precision of the VBA.Timer() function intead of the rounded-to-the-second VBA.DateTime funtions.

Your code is probably something like a loop that checks for some event (a file appearing in a folder?) or a function that's true when data has returned from a lengthy calculation:

```
For i = 1 To 16777216
```

Sleep 10
    '  boolAAAAAGGGHHHH = HasGreatCthulhuEmergedFromTheDeep()
    '  If boolAAAAAGGGHHHH = True Then Exit For
    '
Next i

So all you need to do now is insert a similar piece of code into the loop, to check the current date and time, and calculate the elapsed interval:

CurrentDate = Date
    CurrentTime = VBA.Timer

dblCurrentDateTime = CurrentDate + (CurrentTime / 24 / 3600)

dblElapsedDateTime = dblCurrentDateTime - dblStartDateTime

If dblElapsedDateTime > dblTimeout Then
        ' Err.Raise -1951535091, "XL Doomwatch App", "Mere mortals shall live another day"
        Exit For
        End If

...It's a very late answer, but this is a fairly common problem.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation :) Even when you were late, it was still useful in the year 2020! (and I liked your "easter eggs")

Comment: @Nigel Heffernan Thank you for a well commented answer. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a time difference you can do something like this.  What resolution do you need? If you use Date variables, you are good to the second, I believe.

```
Sub test()

Dim startdatetime As Date

startdatetime = Now()

' wait 7 seconds (or whatever your code does...)

Application.Wait (Now + 0.00008)

Debug.Print Format(Now() - startdatetime, "s.000")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the timer straddling Midnight last Winter mathematically, rather than coding, but I need to review as the macro causes the laptop fan to come on, even when the Worksheet visibility is False. I don't work over midnight but wanted the macro to be useable by others.

The code is from a Macro L, which logs all successive active Windows in Excel, the whole Macro is findable online, I have managed to get a lot of performance information on a freeze pane (Start & End Time, Work Time logged on & Logged off, unpaid Lunch Breaks & Paid Tech Breaks, Active & Inactive Logged on minutes, Total Active Windows, Total Cumulative Macro Time savings ( the macro saves the current version at every unlock screen after breaks, and a cell deletion prior to logging off, to end the 0.3 second loop delay, if no active window change):

Dim SkipRetryCount As Integer
SkipRetryCount = 0

```
If PreText = WinText Then
```

'Delay 0.3 Second and then GoTo SkipRetry

```
Dim PauseTime, Start, Finish, TotalTime
Dim StartTime As Single
```

'TimeElapsed As Single
Dim StartDate As Date

```
StartDate = Date
StartTime = Timer
PauseTime = 0.3
```

'Overcome Midnight problem of Timer Function (struggled to code this simply, and error handle for just 00:00:00)

```
Dim Adjust
Adjust = (86400 * (Date - StartDate)) - 
(StartTime * (Date - StartDate))
```

'Adjust calculates the PauseTime before the new day at 00:00:00, if the PauseTime straddles Midnight
'if PauseTime straddles Midnight:
'StartTime is reset to zero
'PauseTime is reset to delete PauseTime before Midnight

```
Do While Timer < _
(StartTime - (StartTime * (Date - 
StartDate))) + _
(PauseTime - (PauseTime * (Date - 
StartDate))) + _
(PauseTime * (Date - StartDate)) - Adjust
```

'After a rare PauseTime straddle between two dates, the formula will revert back to the simple version although couldn't isolate necessary calculations to just midnight:
'Do While Timer < StartTime + PauseTime

```
DoEvents
```

'If PauseTime straddle finishes under 00:00:01 (1 Second); or Window change log is under 1 second in a new day:
'only the date is shown, as 00:00:00 has no value
'true check could be done if Timer is coded to include hundredths of a second.

```
Loop
                            
Finish = Timer ' Set end time.
TotalTime = Finish - Start 'Calculate 
total time.
                            
GoTo SkipRetry 'personal add
                            
Else

GoTo Continue 'personal add - hits if not 
bypassed at first If.

End
            
End If

Continue: 'if the previous active window 
does not equal the current active window
```